# $_POSTing to and modifying the WP search results page

Tags: theme-development, search

I have a site which uses `post-name` permalinks. If I use the built in search I am taken to the url

```
www.mysite.com/search/searchterm
```

I have a form which I am using as a custom search popup built into a page

```
    $url = '/search';

    <form id="signup" method="post" action="' . $url . '">
        <input name="search_input" type="text">
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

I want to use this form **and** the default search to go to the same page `www.mysite.com/search/searchterm`

I cannot figure out how to `$_POST` to whatever url wordpress uses to display it's results.

Comment: You talk about pre-populating pages but then you refer to layouts. Are you trying to give post-types some kind of default content or post-types some sort of default styling / layout?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - Completely redid the question after some research

Comment: Will calling `get_search_form()` suffice? It looks like the form would be doing the same thing as the actual search form.

Comment: If I understand the codex, this renders the default search form HTML? I wish to have a default search form as well as my 'custom' form

Answer (score 1):

WordPress submits search, by default to [`bloginfo( 'wpurl' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) with search parameter of `s` set to the search term..  You should be able to do this yourself.  You will need to use `GET` on the form and set `name="s"` in your search field.

That said, I agree with the comment above by @Howdy_McGee that you should be using [`get_search_form()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form).  You should just apply custom CSS to this to achieve your desired appearance.  Your search form can't do anything that this form cannot unless you've extended the search feature of WordPress.

Comment: Ah just beat me to it

Comment: so if I wrapped the output of get_search_form() in a div with a class, I could use that class to overwrite the default CSS for each instance I make, while leaving the default search boxes elsewhere on the site as is?

Comment: @myol Precisely. If you've found a solution, mark your problem as solved by selecting one of the answers as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Got a working version, the input and button must have `name="s"` and `id="searchsubmit"` respectfully and the form `method="get"`

```
$url = home_url('/');

<form role="search" method="get" action="' . $url . '">
    <input name="s" type="search">
    <button id="searchsubmit" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

My roots theme didn't have a `search.php` page so I created one in the main theme directory and used `get_search_query()` to get my results.

I used this way over `get_search_query()` because my search form was already complexly styled and this is easy to return as a string from a function. Also, looking at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form#Default_HTML4_Form), this is essentially the HTML generated. I used the HTML 4 version because I have to support legacy browsers.